# php rich text editor to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie to Php. I'm trying to integrate rich text editor in php, like [NicEdit](http://www.nicedit.com/)

Everything works fine but when I try to insert data into the mysql database the code doesn't work.

I have tried following:

```
1. $Description1=$_POST['Description1'];
$g = htmlspecialchars($Description1);
2. base64_encode ( '$data' )
```

**But both don't work**. I want a working example of a code that demonstrates the inserting the HTML code and retrieving back the code. Just a single variable is enough. If anyone knows how to integrate it, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `htmlspecialchars()`? where is your insertion code? question is unclear..

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not the site where you get working code. You have to show what you have tried and if there are any errors and someone can help you solve it.

Comment: '$data' is not equal to "$data" in PHP

Comment: @SagarGuhe I'm using   mysql_query() function to add data. And the Description1 is the Id of my Texteditor. I'm using htmlspecialchars to convert the '><' symbols and then send data in the insert statement

Comment: first, use mysqli instead of mysql, and we need your sql query if you say the insertion is not working...

Comment: Look up 'prepared statements' for inserting from the form into your mysql table (this lets you safely insert without fear of injection) and look up 'htmlpurifier' for safely escaped text to display.  If you use htmlspecialchars you'll strip out all the formatting tags